# ACI Payon integration failed request

Tags: payment-gateway

I wanted to create an integration for the ACI PAY.ON payment gateway but when I used the following request it's failed, however I got the whole request from the API documentation.

```
curl https://test.oppwa.com/v1/payments \
    -d "authentication.userId=8a8294174e735d0c014e78d0ac5a17ee" \
    -d "authentication.entityId=8a8294174e735d0c014e78d0ac4417ea" \
    -d "authentication.password=bzKZ7yXgWN" \
    -d "amount=10.00" \
    -d "currency=USD" \
    -d "paymentType=PA" \
    -d "paymentBrand=BITCOIN" \
    -d "customParameters[SHOPPER_BITNET_REFUND_ADDRESS]=2NEpMQUX5f7kbq7MdbCz6Ss9bYc1Se73Wiv" \
    -d "customer.email=jane@jones.com" \
    -d "cart.items[0].name=Product 1" \
    -d "cart.items[0].price=9.00" \
    -d "cart.items[0].quantity=1" \
    -d "cart.items[0].description=Basic Product 1" \
    -d "cart.items[0].merchantItemId=Product001"
```

The response:

```
{
  "id":"8a8294495d3c342e015d4be11cef3f4a",
  "paymentType":"PA",
  "paymentBrand":"BITCOIN",
  "result":{
    "code":"600.200.500",
    "description":"Invalid payment data. You are not configured for this currency or sub type (country or brand)"
  },
  "customer":{
    "email":"jane@jones.com"
  },
  "customParameters":{
    "SHOPPER_BITNET_REFUND_ADDRESS":"2NEpMQUX5f7kbq7MdbCz6Ss9bYc1Se73Wiv"
  },
  "cart":{
    "items":[
      {
        "merchantItemId":"Product001",
        "name":"Product 1",
        "description":"Basic Product 1",
        "quantity":"1",
        "price":"9.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  "buildNumber":"0f631cce045c12ea93a5ab7df44d9eef7a3fec55@2017-07-12 09:30:45 +0000",
  "timestamp":"2017-07-16 14:50:30+0000",
  "ndc":"8a8294174e735d0c014e78d0ac4417ea_f4a46e3fa1564e2492f7de2c6bc6f7a4"
}
```

There is the [try out](https://docs.aciworldwide.com/tutorials/server-to-server) version. I don't have too big experience with bitcoin payment so I don't know what I (or the ACI API reference) missed from the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their backend is just not set up for that payment method. It is not anything you have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have entered the wrong paymentType value. It should be "DB" (for debit transactions) instead of "PA", and "CD" (for credit transactions). Feel free to contact ACI support as they can help you with the activation on BIP.